# Update callback running after create via Accepts Nested Attributes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, callback, nested

When I create a `Blog` object, both the `create` and `update` callbacks are triggered in sequence.

In this case, updating the `Blog` object deletes all existing `images` and generates new ones. I want to only generate new `images` on `create`, and delete and re-create them on `update`.

I think it's due to the nested object via `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but I can't seem to find a working alternative.

Is this a Rails bug? How can I force the correct callbacks to only trigger once per action?

```
  class Blog
    has_many :posts
    has_many :images

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts

    after_update :destory_existing_images, if: -> { images.any? }
    after_commit :create_images, on: [:update, :create], if: -> { images.none? }

    private

    def destory_existing_images
      images.destroy_all
    end

    def create_screenshots
      images.create!(tag: title)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you use separate callbacks. Use `after_create_commit` for initialization and `after_update_commit` to update the images.

You could also check if the title changed before you update your images. [Dirty API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html) is great for that, your condition then would look like `if: -> { images.any? && saved_change_to_title? }`.

**Solution**

```
  class Blog
    has_many :posts
    has_many :images

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts

    after_create_commit :create_images, if: -> { images.none? }
    after_update_commit :update_images, if: -> { images.any? && saved_change_to_title? }

    private
    
    def update_images
      images.destroy_all
      images.create!(tag: title)
    end

    def create_images
      images.create!(tag: title)
    end
  end
```

Comment: The `saved_change_to_title?` is a beautiful addition, thank you - this works perfectly!